# Запятая и тире после вставки

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Если тренеру не дадут времени — а руководство клуба не привыкло быть терпеливым, — он (тренер) будет уволен.

Правильно ли я поставил запятую?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, знаки препинания расставлены верно. Это вариант перенесенной запятой, которая ставится после вставки.

Если тренеру не дадут времени **— а руководство клуба не привыкло быть терпеливым,** — он (тренер) будет уволен.

**Пример у Розенталя:**

Когда он начинает сомневаться в себе — **а это с ним изредка происходит,** — он пытается стать рационалистом — вставное предложение примыкает к предшествующей придаточной части сложноподчиненного предложения, и запятая ставится после всей конструкции;

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=125#pp125